# I want to add array element in class selector

Tags: html, jquery

I want to add array element in class selector, I have attached image the result is , I want div separated like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   
   var arr = ['top', 'right', "Bottom", "left"]
   var direction = "";
   $.each(arr, function (index, value) {
       direction += value
   });
   $("#directionSec").html("<div class='directionMain'><span class='directionHeader'><h5>Header</h5>" + "<div id='result' class=" + direction + ">" + direction + "</div>" + "</span>");
})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZYpZ.png)

The result I am getting

```
 <div class="toprightbottomleft"> toprightBottomleft</div>
```

The result I wanted

```
<div class="top">top</div> 
<div class="bottom"> bottom</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your html and an image of what you expect?

Comment: hi @aloisdg, I got the result but I  am trying add a class in div as a element but its showing as topBottomrightleft  I wanted it separately written in <div>

Comment: @radrocker Please read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You mean `"top right Bottom left"` with spaces between the values?

Comment: hi @chazsolo, no the result is  <div class="toprightbottomleft" /> i want the result  div to be separated <div class="top"> <div class="right">

Comment: @bitski, i am new to stackoverflow i will read it and update the question thanks

Comment: Please post the code in the question, and show the exact end result (the HTML) you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append them this way:

```js
var arr = ['top', 'right', "Bottom", "left"]
arr.forEach(element => {
  $('#result').append(`<div class="${element}">${element}</div>`)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

On a side note, you have `"<div id='result' class=" + direction + ">"` in your example, however I'm not sure what you want to appear in the class there.

If you want a list of the array items listed as classes in the result div, like `<div id="result" class="top right Bottom left">`, then change the append in my above example to

```
$('#result').append(`<div class="${element}">${element}</div>`).addClass(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will create a string `'innerHtml'` containing information about those 4 different divs with the appropriate array `arr` values as their class names and their text content.

Afterwards that string will be set as HTML content of `#directionSec`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
   var arr = ['top', 'right', "Bottom", "left"],
   innerHtml = '';
   $.each(arr, function( index, value ) {
     innerHtml += "<div class=' + value + '>' + value + '</div>"; 
   });
   $('#directionSec').html(innerHtml);
})
```

Comment: Thanks allot for the reply @bitski